# How can I programmatically get the upper and lower values of a manually drawn rectangle

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I am using the code below to write a message if blue or red rectangle is drawn manually on a chart. I tried getting the one of the rectangle values using `OBJPROP_PRICE1` but it didn't work. How can I get the upper and lower values of a manually drawn rectangle? Also the way I setup 2 bools, one for each rectangle print condition, makes it only possible for one rectangle of each color to be recognized. What would be an appropriate way for me to get the print condition working regardless of the number of blue or red rectangles?

```
bool hasFoundDemandRect = false;
bool hasFoundSupplyRect = false;

void OnTick()   {
for (int i=ObjectsTotal(); i>=0; i--)  {
         string name = ObjectName(i);

         if (ObjectType(name) == OBJ_RECTANGLE) {
            color rectColor = color(ObjectGetInteger(0,name,OBJPROP_COLOR));
            double price1 = ObjectGetDouble(0,name,OBJPROP_PRICE1);
            if (hasFoundDemandRect == false) {
               if (rectColor == clrBlue)  {
                  Print("a BUY rect has to be created");

                  hasFoundDemandRect = true;
               }
            }
            if (hasFoundSupplyRect == false) {
               if (rectColor == clrRed)  {
                  Print("a SELL rect has to be created");
                  hasFoundSupplyRect = true;
               }
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: Seems you did everything correctly. `ObjectGetDouble(0,name,OBJPROP_PRICE1)` is the correct call if you use mql4, it wont compile in mql5. So please provide MCVE and a set, or do debugging yourself

Comment: @DanielKniaz I forgot that the market was closed when I was testing this. I've updated the code. I'm still trying to figure out how to get my inner conditions for the blue and red rectangles to Print for multiple rectangles. I know I've got to change my bool conditions, since they are limited to recognize only one of each, but not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How can I get the upper and lower values of a manually drawn rectangle?*

```
#define MainWINDOW 0

for ( int i = ObjectsTotal(); i >= 0; i-- )  {

      string name = ObjectName( i );

      if ( ObjectType( name ) == OBJ_RECTANGLE ) {
           double price1 =        ObjectGetDouble(  MainWINDOW, name, OBJPROP_PRICE1 );
           double price2 =        ObjectGetDouble(  MainWINDOW, name, OBJPROP_PRICE2 );
           color  rColor = color( ObjectGetInteger( MainWINDOW, name, OBJPROP_COLOR ) );

           if ( rColor == clrBlue )  {
                Print( "BUY rect was found -----------------------------------" );
                Print( "Obj( ", name, " ): Lower edge is: ", MathMin( price1, price2 ) );
                Print( "Obj( ", name, " ): Upper edge is: ", MathMax( price1, price2 ) );
                continue;
           }

           if ( rColor == clrRed )  {
                Print( "SELL rect was found ----------------------------------" );
                Print( "Obj( ", name, " ): Lower edge is: ", MathMin( price1, price2 ) );
                Print( "Obj( ", name, " ): Upper edge is: ", MathMax( price1, price2 ) );
                continue;
           }
      }
}
```

> **Q** : *What would be an appropriate way for me to get the print condition working regardless of the number of blue or red rectangles?*

Solution for this requires you to implement some sort of object-inventory. Your current code just blindly re-iterates per tick over all of the **`ObjectsTotal()`** number of GUI-objects.

Having worked with a DMA-alike object-repository, I feel confident to confirm, this may work very fast for more than a few hundreds thousands GUI-objects, so the solution is doable.

**`MQL4`** language may use either the native array-based DMA-alike object-repository, or may get support from a **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** model, using external node(s) via ZeroMQ-messaging custom-defined API, where remote DB-engines may manage GUI-objects repository and DMA-alike calls for this problem at scales well above million of GUI-objects and scale beyond the `MQL4`-node's Array/Memory-limits.